# SSH tunneling (jump host) combined with X11 forwarding in Remmina

Tags: ssh, remmina, tunnel, x11-forwarding

I recently installed Remmina and want to use SSH tunneling ("jump host") combined with X11 forwarding. I'm not entirely sure if my wording is right.

I'll explain how I do it manually in the terminal.

Firstly,

```
ssh -X user@login1.website.com
user@login1.website.com's password:
```

Then once I'm in the SSH or it's environment, here I type in the second SSH command:

```
ssh -X user@login2.website.com
user@login2.website.com's password:
```

I have to login through ssh in twice with X11 forwarding, i.e. "-X".

How can you do this in Remmina?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: I don't think it can be done in Remmina. I don't see any way to specify `-X` for the first `ssh` server in Remmina. You may want to write a bash script to do do it from the terminal.